# Fetch all user's first names in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve all user's *firstnames* in my Firebase database. What is the best way to add them to an array?

#### Firebase database

```
-Users
   -UserId1
     - firstname: James
   -UserId2
     - firstname: Jennifer
```

#### Swift code

```
let rootRef = Database.database().reference()  
let query = rootRef.child("Users").queryOrdered(byChild: "firstname")
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { 
    (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let firstname = value?["firstname"] as? String ?? ""
        print(firstname)
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you should use Cloud Firestore ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might just be a typo ;) You should be using `child` inside your loop instead of `snapshot`. For instance, try replacing the following line:

```
let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
```

with:

```
let value = child.value as? NSDictionary
```